# Running dotnet microservice on http://localhost:5000/api/Values throws This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Tags: .net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using this way

```
Amreshs-MacBook-Air:myMicroservice amresh$ dotnet run
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
Content root path: /Users/amresh/myMicroservice
```

throws error

This localhost page can’t be found No web page was found for the web address: `http://localhost:5000/`

Search Google for localhost 5000
HTTP ERROR 404

Project created using

```
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/microservice-tutorial/create
```

Comment: are you doing `http://localhost:5000/api/Values` or `http://localhost:5000/` ?

Comment: Both are shwing same issue, @Matthew

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an update to the sample application was introduced in the 3.0 preview templates. dotnet run should still work but you'll need to enter http://localhost:5000/WeatherForecast into the browser to see output from the service.

They have to decide on how to update the sample.